# Смена изображения при изменении текста

Tags: wpf, изображения

Поставлена задача сделать "Эффект сердцебиения" при смене текста (меняются цифры частота биения).

Т.е. цифра поменялась, картинка сердца сделала тук-тук.

Смотрел оригинал программы через снуп, видно что прописан триггер и 2 картинки сердца, которые при смене текста быстро сменяют друг друга.

Подскажите как правильно прописать данный триггер.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Просмотрел более детально через снуп, увидел что сие действие делается через DataTrigger с Binding`ом

Comment: <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="transpStop" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset"
                                         From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.03" BeginTime="0:0:0.03" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
 </UserControl.Triggers>

И собственно, что должно быть на изображениях:

                         <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,32.002,0,22.011" Width="64.175" Source="2.png" x:Name="first"/>

Comment: <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,32.002,0,22.011" Width="64.175" Source="1.png" >
            <Image.OpacityMask>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
                    <GradientStop x:Name="transpStop" Offset="0" Color="Transparent" />
                    <GradientStop x:Name="blackStop" Offset="0" Color="Black" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Image.OpacityMask>
   </Image>

Answer (score 1):

Решение от топикастера из комментов:

Если кому-то понадобится, решил вопрос следующим образом: Прописал Event

```
<UserControl.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated"> 
        <EventTrigger.Actions> 
            <BeginStoryboard> 
                <Storyboard> 
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="blackStop"          
                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset" 
                       From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.03" />
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="transpStop"
                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset" 
                       From="0" To="1" 
                       Duration="0:0:0.03" BeginTime="0:0:0.03" /> 
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard> 
        </EventTrigger.Actions> 
    </EventTrigger>
</UserControl.Triggers>
```

И собственно, что должно быть на изображениях:

```
<Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,32.002,0,22.011" Width="64.175"
    Source="2.png" x:Name="first"/>

<Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,32.002,0,22.011" Width="64.175"
    Source="1.png" >
    <Image.OpacityMask>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
            <GradientStop x:Name="transpStop" Offset="0" 
                Color="Transparent" />                    
            <GradientStop x:Name="blackStop" Offset="0" Color="Black" />     
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Image.OpacityMask>
</Image>
```